# React - Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. What is wrong my syntax?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

To give a little background:

I'm trying to build a Login Form Page function that detects if the user is already logged. If they are logged in, then a button will appear prompting the user to log out. Like so:  `{user ? userLoggedInAlert() : SignIn()}` If `user` is True, then the button appears, if `user` is false, then they receive the username and password form for login authentication.

I have nailed down all the functionality.
However, when I press on button to **logout** the user out, I receive this error:

```
×
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
```

Here is my code, I think there is something wrong with the `const userLoggedInAlert`

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { selectUser } from '../../features/userSlice';
import SignIn from '../auth/Login';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';
import { logout } from "../../features/userSlice";
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import LogOut from '../auth/Logout';



function LoginUser()
{
    const user = useSelector(selectUser);

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const handleLogout = (e) =>
    {
        if(e) e.preventDefault();

        dispatch(logout());
    };

    const userLoggedInAlert = () =>
    {
        return <Container>
            <span>
                You are already logged in!
            </span>
            <Button
                component={NavLink}
                variant="contained"
                color="primary"
                to="/logout" 
                onClick={function(){ LogOut(); handleLogout()}}
            >
                Do you want to logout?
            </Button>

              </Container>
        };

    return (
        <Container>
            {user ? userLoggedInAlert() : SignIn()}
        </Container>
    );
}
export default LoginUser;
```

- `SignIn()` works just fine, so does my `useDispatch`, and other components necessary to create the code above. I'm pretty sure I just messed up the syntax somewhere in the code above?

Here is my code to `LogOut()`, note that I can logout just fine through other means using this exact same component.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import axiosInstance from '../../axios';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function LogOut() {
    
    const history = useHistory();


    useEffect(() => {
        const response = axiosInstance.post('user/logout/blacklist/', {
            refresh_token: localStorage.getItem('refresh_token'),
        });
        localStorage.removeItem('access_token');
        localStorage.removeItem('refresh_token');
        axiosInstance.defaults.headers['Authorization'] = null;
        history.push('/login');
    });
    return <div>Logout</div>;
};
```

Thank you for any help, I'm stuck here.

EDIT:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.57",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.5.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.11.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-facebook-login": "^4.1.1",
    "react-hook-form": "^6.14.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
```

EDIT EDIT:
I'm struggling to implement the recommended changes, I'm now getting some more errors that are making me confused:

```
Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {logoutUser}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

The above error occurred in the `<useLogOut>` component.

Here is how I'm implementing:
`LoginPortal.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { selectUser } from '../../features/userSlice';
import SignIn from '../auth/Login';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';
import { logout } from "../../features/userSlice";
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import useLogOut from '../auth/Logout';

function LoginUser()
{
    const user = useSelector(selectUser);
    // use hook at component body extracting logoutUser method
    const { logoutUser } = useLogOut();

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const handleLogout = (e) =>
    {
        if(e) e.preventDefault();

        dispatch(logout());
    };

    const UserLoggedInAlert = () =>
    {
        return <Container>
            <span>
                You are already logged in!
            </span>
            <Button
                component={NavLink}
                variant="contained"
                color="primary"
                to="/logout"
                // here now you can save logout user since no hooks are being called
                onClick={function(){ logoutUser(); handleLogout()}}
            >
                Do you want to logout?
            </Button>

              </Container>
        };

    return (
        <Container>
            {user ? <UserLoggedInAlert/> : <SignIn/> }
        </Container>
    );
}
export default LoginUser;
```

`Logout.js` component:

```
import axiosInstance from '../../axios';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function useLogOut() {
    
    const history = useHistory();
  
    // we don't useEffect here, we are only interested in function logoutUser
  
    const logoutUser = () => {
        const response = axiosInstance.post('user/logout/blacklist/', {
            refresh_token: localStorage.getItem('refresh_token'),
        });
        localStorage.removeItem('access_token');
        localStorage.removeItem('refresh_token');
        axiosInstance.defaults.headers['Authorization'] = null;
        history.push('/login');
      }
  
    return { logoutUser }
  };
```

My index.js:

```
import useLogOut from './components/auth/Logout';


const routing = (
    <Router>
                <Route path="/logout" component={useLogOut} />
    </Router>
);

ReactDOM.render(routing, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Would this be the correct path for my index router now that Ive changed it?

New errors:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {logoutUser}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

when you call `Logout` at `onClick` you are calling hooks from your function `Logout` outside of a component body, what's is not allowed.

You can abstract your Logout logic to a custom hook where it returns the `logoutUser` function:

```
export default function useLogOut() {
    
  const history = useHistory();

  // we don't useEffect here, we are only interested in function logoutUser

  const logoutUser = () => {
      const response = axiosInstance.post('user/logout/blacklist/', {
          refresh_token: localStorage.getItem('refresh_token'),
      });
      localStorage.removeItem('access_token');
      localStorage.removeItem('refresh_token');
      axiosInstance.defaults.headers['Authorization'] = null;
      history.push('/login');
    }

  return { logoutUser }
};
```

then you consume your custom hook at your `LoginUser` component body, extracting the `logoutUser` method:

```
function LoginUser()
{
    const user = useSelector(selectUser);
    // use hook at component body extracting logoutUser method
    const { logoutUser } = useLogOut();

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const handleLogout = (e) =>
    {
        if(e) e.preventDefault();

        dispatch(logout());
    };

    const UserLoggedInAlert = () =>
    {
        return <Container>
            <span>
                You are already logged in!
            </span>
            <Button
                component={NavLink}
                variant="contained"
                color="primary"
                to="/logout"
                // here now you can safely logout user since no hooks are being called
                onClick={function(){  handleLogout(); logoutUser()}}
            >
                Do you want to logout?
            </Button>

              </Container>
        };

    return (
        <Container>
            {user ? <UserLoggedInAlert/> : <SignIn/> }
        </Container>
    );
}
export default LoginUser;
```

you can take a step ahead and simplify your `LogOut` component:

```
export default function LogOut() {
    
  const { logoutUser } = useLogOut();

  useEffect(() => {
    logoutUser()
  });
  return <div>Logout</div>;
};
```

**Edit**

for simplicity at your Logout.js do as:

```
export const useLogOut = () => {
    
  const history = useHistory();

  // we don't useEffect here, we are only interested in function logoutUser

  const logoutUser = () => {
      const response = axiosInstance.post('user/logout/blacklist/', {
          refresh_token: localStorage.getItem('refresh_token'),
      });
      localStorage.removeItem('access_token');
      localStorage.removeItem('refresh_token');
      axiosInstance.defaults.headers['Authorization'] = null;
      history.push('/login');
    }

  return { logoutUser }
};

export default function LogOut() {

  const { logoutUser } = useLogOut();

  useEffect(() => {
    logoutUser()
  });
  return <div>Logout</div>;
};
```

at your your Login you import the hook with curly brackets:

```
import { useLogOut } from '../auth/Logout';
```

and at your index.js without the curly brackets you import the component:

```
import LogOut from './components/auth/Logout';


const routing = (
    <Router>
                <Route path="/logout" component={LogOut} />
    </Router>
);
```

Comment: Hi Buzatto, thank you so much for showing me how to fix the error and your coding recommendations. I've been trying to implement them but I'm running into some errors. Could you please check my new EDIT EDIT in my original post?

Comment: In addtion to the new errors above, I'm also getting this one: `Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
`

Comment: you should pass your component at `<Route path="/logout" component={LogOut} />`
not the hook. hook itself is not a component

Comment: the second error is likely `handleLogout()` being called after `history.push`. not sure why you have two logout action but I guess if you change the order `function(){  handleLogout(), logoutUser()}` it will solve your issue

Comment: you create another file with the hook `useLogOut`, and maintain the `LogOut` component. you can also use the hook `useLogOut` inside `LogOut` as I described at the end.

Comment: Okay thank you, sorry there was a typo, I meant to say : `the above ever occurred in the useLogOut component`, related to : `Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {logoutUser})`.

Comment: The error occurs on your index.js because you are not passing Logout but the hook instead. Did you fix that?

Comment: Yes I added your correction to my index. I'm going to do what you said about making a new file for the hook, will report back soon.

Comment: Creating a new file is proving to be difficult for me, sorry I'm new to React and I wish I could interpret your help more. Is there any way I can solve the `logoutUser` and `<useLogOut>` errors without having to make a new file?

Comment: for simplicity, keep your original `Logout` as it was.  paste the `useLogOut` hook in the same file but change first line from the hook `export default function useLogOut() {` to `export const useLogOut = () => {`. with that you can import the hook at Login component as `import { useLogOut } from './samepath'`

Comment: your Logout file will export default the original Logout component like it was

Comment: AH thank you so much for the help. I was getting confused with the exports. I did not know react was able to export both a const and function within a file. And I also NOW see the problem with my two logout actions. Can you identify the exact error where that is?

Comment: nvm fixed it! thanks again for saving my night lol

Answer (score 1):

Components are basically function references, and you are invoking them, so instead of doing `SignIn()`, try `<SignIn />`

edit: and make `userLoggedInAlert` start with upper case, then all together:

`{user ? <UserLoggedInAlert /> : <SignIn />}`

Comment: Thank you Deda for helping me, I have made the changes you recommended and thank you for catching the lowercase mistake. I'm still getting the same error however: `Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.`

Comment: I added a little more detail to my original post, all the imports I use on the current file shown, and dependences for my React.

Comment: again, you are invoking a component here, `onClick={function(){ LogOut(); handleLogout()}}` `LogOut` is a component

Comment: Not quite sure I understand, according to Buzzato there is more to the problem at hand.

Comment: Ok, simple question, why are you calling `LogOut()`?

Comment: I understand the error I made calling it like that instead of stating the proper component.